# Compute Environment Variable on Runtime in Bitbucket Pipe

Tags: docker, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using the [atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy/src/master/) pipe inside my pipeline. Here's the step

```
- step: &deploy
    name: Deploy
    deployment: Test # DON'T CHANGE, it's the fallback
    script:
      - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:1.0.2
        variables:
          APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
          BUILD_VERSION: $(cut -c1-7 <<< $BITBUCKET_COMMIT)
          S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
          S3_KEY: "$APPLICATION_NAME-$BUILD_VERSION"
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
          ENVIRONMENT_NAME: $ENVIRONMENT_NAME
          ZIP_FILE: $ZIP_FILE
```

Now the issue is, that the value of `BUILD_VERSION` is `""`. It's empty. Now the Bitbucket pipeline is basically just a docker image running some things. The step above seems to run `docker container run` while passing the above `variables` using `--env`.

E.g. we have by default `--env=BITBUCKET_COMMIT="$BITBUCKET_COMMIT"` which is the commit hash. We also see `--env=BUILD_VERSION="$(cut -c1-7 <<< $BITBUCKET_COMMIT)"`.

Now this all results to `BUILD_VERSION` to be empty. I tried it locally and it should work, the only explanation I found is: `$BITBUCKET_COMMIT` is empty and the only reason it is empty, is because the expression above gets evaluated before `$BITBUCKET_COMMIT` is available. **I don't see why that should be the case.**

I fixed it by doing the following: (I moved it to a own script step)

```
- step: &deploy
    name: Deploy
    deployment: Test # DON'T CHANGE, it's the fallback
    #clone:
    # enabled: false # Workin with artifacts from previous step.
    script:
      - export BUILD_VERSION=$(cut -c1-7 <<< $BITBUCKET_COMMIT)
      - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:1.0.2 # UNTESTED
        variables:
          APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
          S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
          S3_KEY: "$APPLICATION_NAME-$BUILD_VERSION"
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
          ENVIRONMENT_NAME: $ENVIRONMENT_NAME
          ZIP_FILE: $ZIP_FILE
```

But why does this work? Both script parts run "on the same host", no? So why should it matter? Where's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

A pipe is a YAML mapping, not a string scalar.

Bitbucket Pipelines simply forwards string scalars to the shell running the step. Therefore ordinary shell tricks work just fine there, namely starting a subshell with the `$(command)` syntax.

But pipe mappings trigger a very opinionated docker run instruction instead, as you already noted. You could not paste YAML code in your bash prompt and expect it to work!

Bitbucket Pipelines has some kind of variable interpolation mechanism, so that `$VARIABLE_NAME` will resolve the right value. But I would be doubtful that `${ANYTHING:-"more-complex"}` would work (haven't tried though) and, as you saw, no subshells either.

I'd expect few shell tricks to actually work, variable references being the sole exception that is deliberately implemented with a very similar syntax to what a shell would do.

But I'd expect all YAML tricks to work! E.g. anchors, multiline strings, functions and anything in the language reference.